# Batch Script: Setting Default Terminal Application

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hello i have been trying to change the Default window terminal from terminal to Windows Console Host using batch i could not find any way online and i have zero idea how to do this [the setting im trying to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2ivg.png)

i tried changing it with regkeys but couldn't figure it out please help me

> Tried this it didn't work or it didn't take effect immediately

```
reg delete "HKCU\Console\%%Startup" /v DelegationConsole /f 

reg delete "HKCU\Console\%%Startup" /v DelegationTerminal /f 

reg add "HKCU\Console\%%Startup" /v DelegationConsole /t REG_SZ /d "{B23D10C0-E52E-411E-9D5B-C09FDF709C7D}" /f 

reg add "HKCU\Console\%%Startup" /v DelegationTerminal /t REG_SZ /d "{B23D10C0-E52E-411E-9D5B-C09FDF709C7D}" /f
```

Comment: This question is a better fit for Superuser since you're asking about OS settings, but you should be able to change the values of the `DelegationConsole` and `DelegationTerminal` keys in `HKCU\Console\%%Startup` to both be `{B23D10C0-E52E-411E-9D5B-C09FDF709C7D}`.

Comment: Which Windows version ?

Comment: Please add additional information to your question, not in comments.

Comment: The two `reg delete` command lines are not needed because of `%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe ADD "HKCU\Console\%%%%Startup" /v DelegationConsole /t REG_SZ /d "{B23D10C0-E52E-411E-9D5B-C09FDF709C7D}" /f` with the option `/f` (force overwriting) adds the registry value on not existing or overwrites an existing registry value even on being of a different type. In a batch file each `%` must be escaped with one more `%`. There are needed for that reason four `%` in a batch file to specify the registry key with two `%` in registry hive of current user.

Comment: You need to run in a __command prompt__ window `%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe DELETE "HKCU\Console\%Startup" /f` for the deletion of the wrong added registry key with just one `%` instead of two `%%` in registry key name because of having not escaped each `%` with one more `%` in the batch file.